# How do file permissions apply to symlinks?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, file-permissions, symbolic-link

Let's say you have this structure:

```
+ directory
-- file1
-- file2
-- file3 -> /tmp/file3
```

`file3` is a link to another `file3` somewhere else on the system.

Now let's say I `chmod 777` the directory and all contents inside it. Does my `file3` in `/tmp` receive those permissions? Also, let's say we have the same situation but reversed.

```
/tmp/file3 -> /directory/file3
```

If I apply the permissions on the file being linked to, how does that effect the link?

Comment: Permissions only affect the file, not the symlink.

Comment: N.B. above comment does not quite apply to macOS, see answer from @astralblue below for the surprising behaviour there

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It depends on how you call `chmod` and the platform you are running on.

For example, on a Linux system, `man chmod` says this:

> `chmod`  never  changes the permissions of symbolic links; the `chmod`
>   system call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem
>   since the  permissions  of symbolic links  are never  used.  However,
>   for each symbolic link listed on the command line, `chmod` changes the
>   permissions of the pointed-to file.   In  contrast,  `chmod` ignores
>   symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals.

However, on a Mac, chmod can be used to modify the permissions of a symbolic link using options such as this (from `man chmod`):

> -h  If the file is a symbolic link, change the mode of the link
>   itself rather than the file that the link points to.

For the sake of example, lets assume you are on a Linux machine for the rest of this answer.

If in the first case you run `chmod -R 777 directory` to recursively change the permissions, the link target will not be affected, but if you do `chmod 777 directory/*`, it will.

If you change the permissions on the link target directly, those permissions will carry through (since as man page and [baraboom](https://superuser.com/questions/303040/how-do-file-permissions-apply-to-symlinks/303054#303054) say, the actual link permissions aren't used for anything).

---

Test log for illustration:

```
$ mkdir dir && touch dir/file{1,2} /tmp/file3 && ln -s {/tmp,dir}/file3
$ ls -l dir/* /tmp/file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  0 2011-06-27 22:02 /tmp/file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  0 2011-06-27 22:02 dir/file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  0 2011-06-27 22:02 dir/file2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 10 2011-06-27 22:02 dir/file3 -> /tmp/file3

$ chmod -R 777 dir && ls -l dir/* /tmp/file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  0 2011-06-27 22:02 /tmp/file3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user group  0 2011-06-27 22:02 dir/file1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user group  0 2011-06-27 22:02 dir/file2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 10 2011-06-27 22:02 dir/file3 -> /tmp/file3

$ chmod 700 dir/* && ls -l dir/* /tmp/file3
-rwx------ 1 user group  0 2011-06-27 22:02 /tmp/file3
-rwx------ 1 user group  0 2011-06-27 22:02 dir/file1
-rwx------ 1 user group  0 2011-06-27 22:02 dir/file2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 10 2011-06-27 22:02 dir/file3 -> /tmp/file3
```

Comment: That was a surprise to me too. Next question: who do the permissions on a symlink *mean*?

Comment: @EdwardFalk symlink permissions are not non-restrictive since everything needs to be able to traverse it to get the permissions from the linked file.

Comment: why do permissions on `/tmp/file3` change in your last/third section?

Comment: That happened because of the sentence in the quoted man page, _However, for each symbolic link listed on the command line, `chmod` changes the permissions of the pointed-to file_.  The second `chmod` was given a symlink, `/dir/file3`, so it changed the mode of the target, `/tmp/file3`.

Answer (score 18):

baraboom's and peth's answers are both correct: Permission bits on the symbolic links themselves are irrelevant (except on macOS; see below), and changing permission on a symbolic link – by the `chmod` command-line tool or by the `chmod()` system call – will simply act as if it was performed against the target of the symbolic link.

To quote [the SUSv4/POSIX.1-2008 description of symlink() system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/symlink.html):

> The values of the file mode bits for the created symbolic link are unspecified. All interfaces specified by POSIX.1-2008 shall behave as if the contents of symbolic links can always be read, except that the value of the file mode bits returned in the *st_mode* field of the **stat** structure is unspecified.

Here, “unspecified” leaves room of interpretation for each implementation.  Specifics:

- On Linux (tested using ext4fs), `stat()` returns `st_mode=0777`, no matter what the umask was when the symlink was created; `ls -l` therefore always displays `lrwxrwxrwx` for symbolic links.
- On macOS (HFS) and FreeBSD (both UFS and ZFS), a symbolic link does have its own permission: The `chmod -h` command noted above can change this link permission (which internally uses a non-POSIX `lchown()` system call to achieve this), and the `stat()` system call returns this value for `st_mode`.

Symbolic links on Linux and FreeBSD can always be followed, as specified by POSIX.  In particular, on FreeBSD, this means that the file mode of a symbolic link has no effect at all on access control.

On the other hand, macOS slightly breaks POSIX.  Although a symbolic link can be followed regardless its read permission, `readlink()` fails with `EACCES` (Permission denied) if the user does not have read permission:

```
$ sudo ln -shf target symlink
$ sudo chmod -h 444 symlink
$ ls -l symlink
lr--r--r--  1 root  staff  1 Mar 14 13:05 symlink -> target
$ sudo chmod -h 000 symlink
$ ls -l symlink

ls: symlink: Permission denied
l---------  1 root  staff  1 Mar 14 13:05 symlink
$ echo kthxbye > target
$ cat symlink
kthxbye
```

(Note that the `-> target` portion is missing in the output from the second `ls -l` command, and that `cat symlink` still succeeded and printed the contents of the `target` file even though the user did not have read permission on `symlink`.)

NetBSD apparently offers a special mount option named `symperm` which, if set, causes symbolic link read/execute permissions to control `readlink()` and link traversal.

Comment: Double +1 for exposing this very surprising symlink permission behaviour on macOS -- had to confirm this for myself just now: on a symlink with restrictive permissions, the user cannot resolve the symlink, but can still use it to read and write to the target file!

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is about permissions implied ownership rather than read/write/exec permission bits.

While the permission bits on a symbolic link may not matter, the ownership is important in the case of a sticky-bit directory where everyone can create files such as, oh, `/tmp`.

Alice can create a symlink in `/tmp`, edit it and remove it:

```
alice@~ $ ln -sf /whatever /tmp/mylink
alice@~ $ ln -sf /whatever-else /tmp/mylink
```

But user Bob cannot replace or remove Alice's link (tested on Linux):

```
bob@~ $ rm /tmp/mylink
rm: cannot remove /tmp/mylink: Operation not permitted
```

If Bob could do this, Bob could perpetrate an attack against Alice's resolution of the `/tmp/mylink` path that Alice trusts to be as created.

Normally, removing an object depends on having directory permissions. This applies to symlinks. Bob certainly **can** remove a symlink owned by Alice in a directory that is writable to Bob, which doesn't have the sticky bit.

Answer (score -3):

1. drop the link file (after ensuring it is not used by any process)
2. set umask such a way that the 777-umask=required file permissions
3. create the link file afresh

Comment: How does this answer the question?