# Running ssh-agent doesn't appear to set environment variables

Tags: ssh, zsh

What am I not understanding?

I run `ssh-agent` and it appears to set some environment variables but when I `echo` them, I don't get back what I expect.

```sh
❯ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/pn/b_2jl_j55kl504pvctj2jw2c0000gn/T//ssh-SGC2u3LSE0Gu/agent.6521; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=6522; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 6522;

~
❯ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID


~
❯ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.lfH6wkqh4H/Listeners
```

Comment: Note despite the fact you did not manage to set the variables, the process with PID 6522 is running and listening on the socket. You may want to `kill` it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh-agent` is a separate executable. It can neither set nor change variables and the environment of your shell. Without a debugger, only the shell itself can do this (compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38212/108618)).

Therefore `ssh-agent` generates shell code for a shell to *evaluate*. You actually saw the code printed to your console, but not evaluated. The right way to start a new `ssh-agent` *and* set variables is:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

Notes:

- Manuals and how-tos usually use

  ```
   eval `ssh-agent`
  ```

  because it's a universal syntax that should work in many shells, no matter if `sh`-like or `csh`-like. The command with `"$(…)"` follows modern good practices in `sh`-like shells and your `zsh` is `sh`-like in this context.
- `ssh-agent` tries to tell if your shell is `sh`-like or `csh`-like, and generates shell code accordingly. In other words it behaves like `ssh-agent -s` or `ssh-agent -c`, depending on what it "thinks" about your shell. If you know your shell is `zsh` then you may prefer `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` in case the tool guesses wrong for some reason. Usually this is not needed though.
- Almost always [you should avoid `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/10765659), in general it's hard to use it safely, some say "`eval` is evil". With `ssh-agent` [it's OK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640716/108618) though, because `ssh-agent` is deliberately designed to be used with `eval`, it generates fully controlled shell code that stays away from areas and pitfalls that make eval "evil".