# List of ssh keys provided by ssh agent on a remote machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Locally keys made available by ssh agent can be listed using `ssh-add -L`. When connected to a remote machine through ssh, is there a way to list keys made available through ssh agent from the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You do forward the local agent, right? If so, then the command is the same: `ssh-add -L`. `ssh-add` connects to the socket specified by `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and if you have used `ssh -A` then the remote socket leads to your local agent and thus remote `ssh-add` (or any tool that uses the socket) will talk to the local agent.

You can even `ssh-add` a remote key (remote from your point of view; local from the point of view of `ssh-add` running on the server) and your local agent will be able to use it even after you disconnect.

<sup>(More complicated tricks are possible. E.g. [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1735263/432690) describes "borrowing" keys, but in the opposite direction: a local key is added to an agent running on the server.)</sup>

Note `ssh-add -L` will show you pathnames of added keys with no indication of where (what host) each key came from. You can add one key with `ssh-add /foo/bar` locally and you can add another key with `ssh-add /foo/bar` invoked on the server (when the agent is forwarded!), and `ssh-add -L` (locally or on the server) will show you two different keys described as `/foo/bar`.